# Is it possible to refer to postman call name within the tests body

Tags: postman

App Details:

```
Postman for Chrome
Version 5.0.1
win / x86-64
Chrome 58.0.3029.110
```

In my collection, I have various requests within folders.
e.g. `Collection>CollectionFolder1>Request1, Request2 ...`

Is it possible to get a **reference of the request names** within the tests so that I could write something like:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (e) {
    tests[Test failed with exception ${e} for call request ${SOME_VARIABLE_THAT_STORES_REQUEST_NAME}] = false
}
```

This would allow me to duplicate this skeleton in all my requests without having to bother about maintaining it.

Is there any postman variable or structure that would store any such info.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox - paragraph Request/response related properties you can use the 'request' object.

<strike>`request.name`: gives you the current test case name</strike> **Obsolete** use `pm.info.requestName`

`request.method`: gives you the method used (PUT, GET, etc.)

`request.url`: gives you the target url

In order to see all the available data you may use, I suggest you to open the console (View/Show postman console or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and see the data returned by this:
`console.log(request)`

Comment: You have to use pm.info.requestName now, from the request Object you can have some other info in read-only:  https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

Comment: @bastaPasta indeed, you may have a look to the next answer from Dan Krueger, no need to downvote ...

Answer (score 21):

Postman v6.5.2 and up uses `pm.info.requestName`

```
console.log("Running: "+ pm.info.requestName);
```

Look at `pm.info` object:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-with-request-info