# Postman Get Gmail Email ID, Iterate Through Email IDs?

Tags: javascript, postman, gmail-api

Fairly new to postman, I have never quite wrapped my head around iterating through message IDs when chaining API requests.

I have a simple GET request as follows

https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user/messages

This works no problem and retrieves the first 100 messages in my inbox, I am using the index to then chain to another command to open that email and inspect the contents with the following code

```
Responsedata = JSON.parse(responseBody)
Value = Responsedata.messages[1].id
console.log(Value)
pm.environment.set("email_id", Value);
```

What I can't figure out is how to iterate and increment that message[1].id from 1 to 2 on the next iteration? I have never quite wrapped my head around incrementing variables, if that's even how you would describe this.

JSON response body

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "175ec820de8d5815",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ec63d888a91e4",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ec4ac78ad714c",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ec387d20eca9e",
            "threadId": "175ec387d20eca9e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ec2e523051b86",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ebec54123045d",
            "threadId": "175ebec54123045d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ebc70bb0706ad",
            "threadId": "175ebc70bb0706ad"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ebb034f6b4e45",
            "threadId": "175ebb034f6b4e45"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb9b037fb323d",
            "threadId": "175eb9b037fb323d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb92ff22a18e7",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb6e43ed84e8a",
            "threadId": "175eb6e43ed84e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb4a53485253e",
            "threadId": "175eb4a53485253e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb3863d4e91e6",
            "threadId": "175eb3863d4e91e6"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb29ca100bd4b",
            "threadId": "175eb29ca100bd4b"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eb1e07c2a79c5",
            "threadId": "175eb1e07c2a79c5"
        },
        {
            "id": "175eaa249502f250",
            "threadId": "175eaa249502f250"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ea4c7a0f60ea8",
            "threadId": "175ea4c7a0f60ea8"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e966814c59a2f",
            "threadId": "175e966814c59a2f"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e90fb0b4e92c7",
            "threadId": "175e90fb0b4e92c7"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e902d58899476",
            "threadId": "175e902d58899476"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e901dd3bf8c1a",
            "threadId": "175e901dd3bf8c1a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e8d3d2c2e2cdf",
            "threadId": "175e8d3d2c2e2cdf"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e88cc6625e8f7",
            "threadId": "175e88cc6625e8f7"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e8886780eb458",
            "threadId": "175e8886780eb458"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e8849c2580f35",
            "threadId": "175e8849c2580f35"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e860f338f99fd",
            "threadId": "175e860f338f99fd"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e826813c2512a",
            "threadId": "175e826813c2512a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e8182b6d6fd4c",
            "threadId": "175e8182b6d6fd4c"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e811ddaa99f73",
            "threadId": "175e811ddaa99f73"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e804e4132a8f7",
            "threadId": "175e804e4132a8f7"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7e5c4e038d51",
            "threadId": "175e7e5c4e038d51"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7d67ca17d9a4",
            "threadId": "175e7d67ca17d9a4"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7b10aae82ff4",
            "threadId": "175e7b10aae82ff4"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7afe6336473d",
            "threadId": "175e7afe6336473d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7aab7ffa8caf",
            "threadId": "175e7aab7ffa8caf"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7921f0aa2d37",
            "threadId": "175e7921f0aa2d37"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e7909f1cd7f21",
            "threadId": "175e7909f1cd7f21"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e77c5c38b3eea",
            "threadId": "175e77c5c38b3eea"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e767ba83807d9",
            "threadId": "175e767ba83807d9"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e766141962d76",
            "threadId": "175e766141962d76"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e74db2fbd3b95",
            "threadId": "175e74db2fbd3b95"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e740bcad276eb",
            "threadId": "175e740bcad276eb"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e72a7faeb4afe",
            "threadId": "175e72a7faeb4afe"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e70303a877f7f",
            "threadId": "175e70303a877f7f"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e6d1f9378159e",
            "threadId": "175e6d1f9378159e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e6c4fd22ca201",
            "threadId": "175e6c4fd22ca201"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e6a219df346d2",
            "threadId": "175e6a219df346d2"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e69d61bbda68d",
            "threadId": "175e69d61bbda68d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e69aca8a3f6b4",
            "threadId": "175e69aca8a3f6b4"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e671ee477728e",
            "threadId": "175e671ee477728e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e669f68a6449d",
            "threadId": "175e669f68a6449d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e660cc2fa4a2b",
            "threadId": "175e660cc2fa4a2b"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e644571920dcb",
            "threadId": "175e644571920dcb"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e63597c815898",
            "threadId": "175e63597c815898"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e62fdaa7db163",
            "threadId": "175e62fdaa7db163"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e607b5e54d4a4",
            "threadId": "175e607b5e54d4a4"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e5fadc78ecb2d",
            "threadId": "175e5fadc78ecb2d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e5f62a75c7830",
            "threadId": "175e5f62a75c7830"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e5ce2503f0ed5",
            "threadId": "175e5ce2503f0ed5"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e59fb2a92ed04",
            "threadId": "175e59fb2a92ed04"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e58a770f24835",
            "threadId": "175e58a770f24835"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e47edfee50b0f",
            "threadId": "175e47edfee50b0f"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e479d78f5c82d",
            "threadId": "175e479d78f5c82d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e443dc96e8ee1",
            "threadId": "175e443dc96e8ee1"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e4208a9f1d919",
            "threadId": "175e4208a9f1d919"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e37e1f1ee5661",
            "threadId": "175e37e1f1ee5661"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e37202f407a9e",
            "threadId": "175e37202f407a9e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e35c496cb1b0f",
            "threadId": "175e35c496cb1b0f"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e35b4b9ba2206",
            "threadId": "175e35b4b9ba2206"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e32afb4abbdc7",
            "threadId": "175e32afb4abbdc7"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e31871a2314c9",
            "threadId": "175e311c47b275c3"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e283047fd2ac8",
            "threadId": "175e283047fd2ac8"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e26ef899364ca",
            "threadId": "175e26ef899364ca"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e25febda101eb",
            "threadId": "175e25febda101eb"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e251ed002c537",
            "threadId": "175e251ed002c537"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e21e252f693b7",
            "threadId": "175e21e252f693b7"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e2195e9789de5",
            "threadId": "175e2195e9789de5"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e203db4446415",
            "threadId": "175e203db4446415"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e1e2af08f9c8a",
            "threadId": "175e1e2af08f9c8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e1dc3064e0ed3",
            "threadId": "175e1dc3064e0ed3"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e18fa88a2e964",
            "threadId": "175e18fa88a2e964"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e168dd1c91145",
            "threadId": "175e168dd1c91145"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e15e336efaf17",
            "threadId": "175e15e336efaf17"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e12adedb64c27",
            "threadId": "175e12adedb64c27"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e1225c1cd0d92",
            "threadId": "175e1225c1cd0d92"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e115ded941cb2",
            "threadId": "175e115ded941cb2"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e0c0d4699ee7c",
            "threadId": "175e0c0d4699ee7c"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e007c6c86b017",
            "threadId": "175e007c6c86b017"
        },
        {
            "id": "175e0045b0ccfd3a",
            "threadId": "175e0045b0ccfd3a"
        },
        {
            "id": "175dfb57449a79a5",
            "threadId": "175dfb57449a79a5"
        },
        {
            "id": "175df2b0d97a4d3b",
            "threadId": "175df2b0d97a4d3b"
        },
        {
            "id": "175def4df0296793",
            "threadId": "175def4df0296793"
        },
        {
            "id": "175deb0de0d5f556",
            "threadId": "175deb0de0d5f556"
        },
        {
            "id": "175de5e09969f8c4",
            "threadId": "175de5e09969f8c4"
        },
        {
            "id": "175de5764bd6fb74",
            "threadId": "175de5764bd6fb74"
        },
        {
            "id": "175de36602c22133",
            "threadId": "175de36602c22133"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ddff4c43350c1",
            "threadId": "175ddff4c43350c1"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ddb71d738d02e",
            "threadId": "175ddb71d738d02e"
        },
        {
            "id": "175ddb286746873d",
            "threadId": "175ddb286746873d"
        },
        {
            "id": "175dd91c62c5ed50",
            "threadId": "175dd91c62c5ed50"
        }
    ],
    "nextPageToken": "10494810510912086965",
    "resultSizeEstimate": 618
}
```

Editing for the second portion,

I am then taking that email_id and doing another GET request

[https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user/messages/{{email_id}}](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user/messages/%7B%7Bemail_id%7D%7D)

Which then opens and reads the contents of the email, this is why I am trying to increment that email_id index from 0 to 1, so each time I run the API chain it moves onto the next email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let temp = []
jsonData.messages.forEach((b)=>{
    temp.push(b.id)
})
    
pm.environment.set("emailID",temp)
    
console.log(pm.environment.get("emailID"))
```

You can store an array or anything as an environmental variable. Postman works just like Javascript.

Now you have value in the `emailID` variable. Now you can send the message with id request using `setNextRequest`.

If your request name and structure is like:

First getting messages then get a message with ID:

[image]

Then use below pre-request script in the GET message with id request:

```js
let emailIDList = pm.environment.get("emailID");
    
    
pm.environment.set("id", emailIDList.pop())
pm.environment.set("emailID", emailIDList)
if (emailIDList.length > 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest("get Message with id")
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to work on my javascript, I am out of my realm. It seems this solution as you describe, put all the IDs in an array, Assuming on my next step when I call "emailID" I could point to the index of the array then increment that index to shuffle through each email? In my mind the program would iterate through the request 100 times, each time selecting the next email ID and checking it against a set of values in the next get request. Assuming it is easier to do a get request for the whole list, then iterate over that array?

Comment: @Josh where is it interesting over request ? It is iterating over response .

Comment: Sends a request , gets the response , stores all email IDs in the response to an array . Now you do what you want to do with the ids

Comment: Sorry, this is my first postman post so maybe I'm the problem as I did not put in my additional get request in the initial question...let me add that in so you can see what I am doing, I am taking the said ID back from the response, and then using that ID in another get request to open up the email from the ID.

Comment: @Josh added the full solution , now we will send first request only once and second reqeust 100 times with each email_id value

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking to do. This now allows the email ID to increment then be stored in the id var. I think what threw me off (Among multiple things) was the pre-request portion, I kept putting it all under tests and forgot about that section which would run prior to the request. I am going to work on some Javascript skills as I am lacking on that. HUGE HELP.

Comment: I am stuck on something very similar again, can you explain the significance of the `jsonData.messages.forEach((b)=>{
    temp.push(b.id)` statement? I tried to reuse this piece but had issues. Is that "id" in the push.(b.id) section the environment variable created in the pre-request script? If so now I know why my new request would not work as I am using a different environment. Thank you

Comment: I was able to work this one back and figure out what .messages rooted from, within the response of the json body, then the id as well. I was able to make this work by changing those items. Thanks again for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well the question, but in order to increment the value of the `messages[1].id`, just do :

`Responsedata.messages[1].id++`

That will increment (by one) the `messages[1].id` value.

[image: response++]

**Otherwise**, if you want to iterate over 100 messages contained within the Responsedata object, you can do (since messages is an array) :

```
Responsedata = JSON.parse(responseBody)
for(let i = 0; i < Responsedata.messages.length; i++)
{
     Value = Responsedata.messages[i].id
     console.log(Value)
     // do wathever you want with each message
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dorian, thanks for the reply. I had thought I tried that, I went back and edited it to be `Responsedata = JSON.parse(responseBody)
Value = Responsedata.messages[1].id++
console.log(Value)
pm.environment.set("email_id", Value); ` but it still did not fetch the next ID in my inbox on the next iteration. Perhaps I'm still implementing this wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the responseBody json content ? That would help us to understand the problem. Also, for your information, `Value = Responsedata.messages[1].id++`, if i'm not wrong, will assign the 
 `Responsedata.messages[1].id` to the "Value" variable and only afterwards, it will increment by one the `Responsedata.messages[1].id` value.

Comment: Just updated original question with response body. Thanks! Do I need to make it an environment variable or anything? I am new to postman as stated...but wouldn't the variable always default back to index [1] since it would re-run every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest iterating over the ids array and send an HTTP request for each id using `pm.sendRequest()`.

```
const ids = pm.response.json().messages.map(item => item.id);

for (let id of ids) {
    const url = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user/messages/${id}`
    pm.sendRequest(url, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            pm.test(`200 OK for id '${id}'`, () => pm.expect(result.code).to.eql(200));
        }
    })
}
```

I personally prefer to use pm.sendRequest(), as:

1. you have more control during the script execution;
2. `postman.setNextRequest` has no effect when you run requests using the Send button, it only comes into effect when you run a collection.